# How to make OpenSSL with SHA256 instead of sha1?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

I'm trying to make a private key for an SSL certificate on localhost using wamp64.
I have downloaded the Shining Light Productions OpenSSL for windows 64 bit and I can make a private key using sha1.

The following bit of code works (to my relief)

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt - days
```

However when opening the site in Chrome50+ it informs me that the site is not secure because of the SHA1 depreciated through its security vulnerabilities.Can I use x509 with sha256 or is there a better command?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: ***`CN=example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use sha256. Try with `-sha256` option (instead of `-sha1`):

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 ....
```

Comment: This worked I was wondering whether X509 was going to play along with the updated hash. Thanks you earned an easy point. ;)